# MSVC C6029 Warning: possible buffer overrun, use of unchecked value. The warning does not disappear when checking the buffer size

Tags: c++, visual-c++, warnings, buffer-overflow

I have annoying C6029 warning in my code ([description of the error on the Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/c6029?view=vs-2019)).

For example:

```
#include <cstdio> // fopen, fseek, fread, fclose

static constexpr size_t MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 100;

void foo(const FILE* myFILE)
{
    double buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE]{};
    size_t bufferSize = 0;

    std::fread(&bufferSize, sizeof(size_t), 1, myFILE);

    std::fread(buffer, sizeof(double), bufferSize, myFILE); // C6029 Warning.       
}
```

It disappears only if one specific check is observed (like example in error description):

```
#include <cstdio> // fopen, fseek, fread, fclose
static constexpr size_t MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 100;
void foo(const FILE* myFILE)
{
    double buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE]{};
    size_t bufferSize = 0;

    std::fread(&bufferSize, sizeof(size_t), 1, myFILE);  

    if(sizeof(double) * bufferSize > sizeof(buffer))
    {
        return;
    }

    std::fread(buffer, sizeof(double), bufferSize, myFILE); // No C6029 Warning.        
}
```

Such a solution does not suit me, because if the permissible value is exceeded, I still need to read other things from the file.

But if I check an equivalent case, the warning remains:

```
#include <cstdio> // fopen, fseek, fread, fclose
static constexpr size_t MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 100;
void foo(const FILE* myFILE)
{
    double buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE]{};
    size_t bufferSize = 0;

    std::fread(&bufferSize, sizeof(size_t), 1, myFILE);    

    if(sizeof(double) * bufferSize <= sizeof(buffer))
    {
        std::fread(buffer, sizeof(double), bufferSize, myFILE); // C6029 Warning, again.
    }           
}
```

At the same time, if you slightly modify the check recommended by Microsoft so that an error occurs, the warning will magically disappear:

```
#include <cstdio> // fopen, fseek, fread, fclose
static constexpr size_t MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 100;
void foo(const FILE* myFILE)
{
    double buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE]{};
    size_t bufferSize = 0;

    std::fread(&bufferSize, sizeof(size_t), 1, myFILE);

    if(sizeof(double) * bufferSize <= sizeof(buffer))
    {
        // DO NOTHING...
    }   

    std::fread(buffer, sizeof(double), bufferSize, myFILE); // Wow, magic! No C6029 Warning.        
}
```

This error warning annoys me very much. Of course, I can simply not pay attention to it, but still I want to get rid of it in a "legitimate" way (and preferably not syntactically terrible).

Comment: "_Such a solution does not suit me, because if the permissible value is exceeded, I still need to read other things from the file._" Ok, but you should never exceed the buffer so the check should still be there. Why not use a `vector<double>` and an `ifstream`?

Answer (score 1):

> Such a solution does not suit me, because if the permissible value is
>   exceeded, I still need to read other things from the file.

Then do not `std::fread` the offending part for what you do not have buffer. For example you can `std::fseek` over it. Or you can allocate large enough buffer dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

The first version of `foo` you posted will overrun the buffer if the data in the input file is too large.  The compiler is therefore quite right to issue a warning.

The best solution is probably to allocate the buffer dynamically (error checking omitted for brevity):

```
void foo(FILE* myFILE)
{
    double *buffer;
    size_t bufferSize = 0;
    std::fread(&bufferSize, sizeof(size_t), 1, myFILE);
    buffer = new double [bufferSize];
    std::fread(buffer, sizeof(double), bufferSize, myFILE);
    ...
    delete [] buffer;
}
```

Note: you cannot pass `myFILE` as `const` - `fread` needs to modify the object.  Also, checkout [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) to assist with memory management in cases like this.